# Deleting all occurrences of UID in Realtime Database using Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am wanting to add a cloud function to my Firebase app that listens for when users are deleted. Whenever a user is deleted, any occurrence the deleted user's UID in my database should be deleted as well.

My app is similar to tinder in the fact that you can "match" with other users. So, each user object in my database has the property "matches" which is a dictionary of other users that they've matched with. The keys in the "matches" dict is the matched user's UID while the value is the UNIX timestamp at which the users matched. It looks something like this:

```
Users
    |
    |___ abcdefg12345
    |        |___ name: "User 1"
    |        |___ matches
    |                |___ zyxwvut98765: 1575135895.6376572
    |                |___ c6h7d8m9a0y7: 1575135903.1829304
    |
    |___ zyxwvut98765
    |        |___ name: "User 2"
    |        |___ matches
    |                |___ abcdefg12345: 1575135895.6376572
    |
    |___ c6h7d8m9a0y7
    |        |___ name: "User 3"
    |        |___ matches
    |                |___ abcdefg12345: 1575135903.1829304
    |
```

So in the above example, whenever `Users/abcdefg12345` is deleted, I need my cloud function to delete both `Users/zyxwvut98765/matches/abcdefg12345` and `Users/c6h7d8m9a0y7/matches/abcdefg12345`.

I know how to update individual user objects using cloud functions via something like:

```js
let uid = "c6h7d8m9a0y7";
let dic = ["name":"User 3", "matches":[]];
admin.database().ref('Users').child(uid).update(dic);
```

I am able to listen for user deletions and grab the UID of the user deleted via:

```js
exports.deleteListener = functions.database.ref('/Users/{User}').onDelete((snapshot, context) =>
{
    let uid = context.params.User;
    console.log(uid);
});
```

I am just unsure how to delete a potentially infinite number of individual nodes after I've grabbed this deleted UID.

Comment: The way your data is structured right now, you have a lot of querying to do to find all the child nodes to delete.  If you have any chance of migrating to Firestore, this will become a *lot* easier with a single collection group query.

Comment: That's a possibility. In the meantime, with realtime database it will be a matter of looping though all matched users and removing the deleted user node manually?

Comment: That's about the sum of it.

Comment: There isn't any way to see the entire user tree within the `onDelete` event listener, is there? This way I'd be able to see what users the deleted user was matched with. Or is the `onDelete` listener called after the node is already deleted?

Comment: Nevermind, seeing that `onDelete` is, in fact, called *after* the deletion has occurred. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DavidChopin inside onDelete do snaphot.key does it give u the id

Comment: @PeterHaddad this simply returns the UID, which I already have.

Comment: "delete a potentially infinite number of individual nodes" I doubt the number will be as high as infinity. And you can delete quite a lot of data in one go. Just so I understand correctly: when you delete a user, you also want to delete their UID from any matches, which can be found under the deleted user's `matches` node. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, @FrankvanPuffelen that is correct. The number is more likely to be around 20ish at a max. The problem is, there doesn't appear to be a way to retrieve the user object's "matches" dictionary within the `onDelete` handler.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if there were a way, however, to return all nodes that match `Users/{uid}/matches/abcdefg12345`, I could loop through and delete each one. When deleting `Users/abcdefg12345`, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all of this with a single `update()` statement, as long as you have a reasonable list of children.

```js
exports.deleteUser = functions.database.ref('/Users/{User}').onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
  let uid = context.params.User;
  let matches = snapshot.val().matches;
  let updates = {};
  Object.keys(matches).forEach((key) => {
    updates[`/Users/${key}/matches/${uid}`] = null;
  });
  return admin.database().ref().update(updates);
});
```

Comment: You are a godsend! Let me try it out and get back to you (I'm in class right now, so it may be a bit)

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `\`/Users/${match.key}/matches/uid\`: null`? I'm having a hard time deploying because the `:` is unexpected within the `map` function.

Comment: Ah, got it... The backticks are what's known as a template string. But I see I have a typo, so let me fix that..

Comment: Yeah with typescript, backticks essentially allow concatenation through `${}`, right? It also seems that we need the *keys* of matches, I've nearly got it figured out on my own.

Comment: I was having a hard time with the `map()` function, so ended up using `forEach`. That should work now, with the backticks still indicating a template string, where it expands the `${match.key}` into the key of the match. So you end up with a map with the keys being the paths to the nodes you want to remove, and the value being `null` (which is how you can remove a value).

Comment: It worked almost perfectly, I edited your answer with the subtle changes I had to add to make it work. Thanks puf!

Comment: Thanks for the edit David! I have no idea why I couldn't figure out the correct `forEach` incantation, but am glad you got it working. :)

Comment: The issue is that `matches` was an object (`{"zyxwvut98765":1575135895.6376572,"c6h7d8m9a0y7":1575135903.1829304}`), not an array, thus `forEach` wouldn't work on it. We first have to convert `matches` to an array of keys via `Object.keys(matches)`. We can then iterate through them.